# Viewing of stack during yacc parsing

Tags: parsing, yacc

Is there a way to see the stack(for better understanding of working of yacc) during each step of yacc parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using YACC or Bison? Bison has this:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Tracing.html

yacc seems to have something similar with a -t command line option, but I haven't used it.

Comment: i am using yacc but dont mind using bison. I tried this and could not get it to work.

Comment: It might be worth trying Bison to learn how these parsers work, even if you continue to use yacc for production. It's open source so you can dig as deeply as you like.